# How to script: If value is this:xxx do this, BUT if value is this:yyyy then do this instead

Tags: javascript

Looking for a how-to from the JavaScript gurus out there.
I'm not a developer, but mine is away for a while and I need to adapt a script. It is for handling specific email and is written if the email header contains *THIS* email address and the subject contains *THIS INFORMATION* or ***THIS** information* then grab this data from the email and make a ticket assigned to this group with this information...

```js
if (headers.indexOf('####.####@yadayadablah.ca') > -1 && 
   (subject.indexOf('Test text: More test text') > -1 ||
   subject.indexOf('FW: Even more test text') > -1)) { 

    // get user information
    var userFrom = '';
    var usr = new GlideRecord('sys_user');
    usr.addQuery('sys_id', email.from_sys_id);
    usr.query();
    if (usr.next()) {
        userFrom = ' from ' + usr.first_name + ' ' + usr.last_name;
    }

    // generate incident when phishing email is forwarded
    var inc = new GlideRecord('incident');
    inc.initialize();
    inc.caller_id = email.from_sys_id;
    inc.assignment_group = '2819caca1beb9c904b8c74ce0a4bcb33';
    inc.category = 'security'; // security 9441ce03db00d700dd0736ee9d96193a
    inc.subcategory = 'phishing';
    inc.contact_type = 'email';  // bbd7cb4bdbc73300dd0736ee9d961902 email
    inc.short_description = 'Suspected Phishing Attempt: ' + email.subject;
    inc.description = 'Email Body: '+ email.body_text;
    inc.insert();

    event.state = "stop_processing";
    
}

// email to send
/*
var gr = new GlideRecord('sys_email');
gr.initialize();
gr.type = 'send-ready';
gr.recipients = email.origemail;
gr.subject = 'Notification update: Insert app name here Update This Phishing 
Test';
gr.body = '<p><strong><span style="color: #a83e32;">ATTENTION:</span> This 
was just a test</strong></p>' + 
'<p>An Incident has been created with your reponse. You can view details at 
<a href="/ssp?id=ticket&table=incident&sys_id=' + inc.sys_id + '">' + 
inc.number + '</a></p>';

gr.insert();
*/
```

What I need is to edit this so it does one thing if the header is the one group and it does another if the header is this other group...
I have no idea how to script that part, and this cannot wait until Monday when my Dev gets back.

Any and all suggestions are hugely appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Sounds like you want an `if`-`else` statement, but the code here is incomplete and the email format isn't available, so more information seems necessary to make the question answerable.

Comment: Greetings ggorlen.
Thank you for the feedback. I have edited the snippet to show the entire script.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still incomplete--if you hit the run button, you'll see `"Uncaught ReferenceError: headers is not defined"`. Most of the relevant data input to the program isn't shown. The idea is that the snippet is a [mcve] such that it can be fully executed to show the problem, along with a description (and preferably literal output) of the behavior/result you need. Without that, it's guesswork...

Comment: I wonder if it's because this is within ServiceNow as an Inbound Action for email. The rest of the input data is handled by the gui. Does that make sense?

As it is, the script works, but what we realised is that the one recipient address may not be the only place the message is sent, and we want similar behaviour to take place if the message is sent to another specific group.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for an if-else statement, this could look like this:

```
if(value == xxx){
doSomething();
}else if(value == yyy){
doSomethingElse();
}
```

Comment: Greetings grosseklappe2... So, looking at the snippet I provided, I need to put the
else if(value == yyy){
doSomethingElse();

right before the event.state = "stop_processing"; line?

Comment: if I understand what you want to do correctly, yes.

Comment: Thank you. I am assuming when I see exclamation marks next to lines of code with the message: "value is already defined" that I've done it wrong? lol

Comment: I'm not really sure what the meaning of that "exclamation mark message" could be, maybe I could help you, if you would send me a screenshot.

Comment: I can do that... I think

Comment: Nope. apparently I can't